# SQLIte and recursive data

Tags: recursion, sqlite

Say, I have table T where some row can contain reference to another row in the same table. Generally speaking I want to build recursive entity. What is most appropriate and efficient way to do that using SQLite?

Comment: What exactly are you asking about, how to *create* such a table, or how to *recursively query* such a table?

Comment: Both. Appropriate data structure, querying and updating

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html).