# SQLite and recursive structures

Tags: recursion, sqlite, tree, recursive-query

This is continuation of question [SQLIte and recursive data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40299173/sqlite-and-recursive-data) .
Say I want to save trees in SQLite. Each node/leave has exactly the same data structure, but any 2 trees can **share** 0 or more nodes or leaves. Number of trees is undefined.
So what can be proper schema for that?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I can propose so far is to create table with data:

```
create table main (dataid int, data text);
```

and then for each tree dynamically create new table:

```
create table tree (dataid int, parent references (tree), foreign key dataid references main(dataid) on delete cascade );
```

If anybody can do better - welcome.

Comment: You don't need a separate table for each tree. Each tree can be represented by its root node, which has a `NULL` parent.